# Как реализовать схему с ролями и юзерами в rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал все таблицы, вопрос в том как обратиться к таблице `UsersRoles`, которую я создавал через миграцию (`create_join_table`) и создать связь `owner_id` -> `id` (`users_roles`)?

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что таблицы у вас названы не по конвенциям Rails и без явного указания Rails их просто не увидит, верно?

Comment: К сожалению нет, а что не так?

Comment: В принципе мой вопрос как правильно это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

А почему вы делаете связь животных на таблицу связей роли - пользователи, а не к таблице с пользователями? Ведь пользователь легко может лишиться роли.

Можно сделать так:

```
rails generate model User name
rails generate model Role name
# в миграции можно добавить внешние ключи и индексы
rails generate migration CreateJoinTableUserRole user role
rails generate model Pet name user:references

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class Pet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Это создаст следующую структуру(не считая таймстемпов, конечно):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в вашем примере получается что животное принадлежит User хотя должено принадлежать UserRole

Answer (score -1):

Рекомендую воспользоваться замечательным `gem`'ом [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Comment: Но там нет ролей.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/